# Haml wont allow erb output to render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have two templates

test.html.haml
test.html.erb

both have the same content

```
<%= 1+1 %>
```

output for haml (wrong)

```
%= 1+1 %>
```

output for erb (correct

```
2
```

how do I get the haml file to allow ruby output

Comment: show the code content a bit more please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a haml file with the following content:

```
<%= 1+1 %>
```

That is ERB syntax, you need to use [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) syntax.

```
= 1 + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a HAML file instead of a eRB file, you need to use HAML syntax instead of eRB syntax:

```
= 1 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here [**`How to Convert`**](http://haml.info/tutorial.html)

***ERB***

```
<strong><%= item.title %></strong>
```

***Haml***

```
%strong= item.title
```